# Open QgsColorDialog and modify feature in @qgsfunction from expressions

Tags: pyqgis, color, feature-layer, qgsexpression, dialog

Is it possible to open a QDialog (here a `QgsColorDialog`) and modify layer's feature when executing a QgsExpression with a qgsfunction such as :

```
@qgsfunction(args="auto")
def label_annotation(feature, parent, context):
    color_dialog = QgsColorDialog()
    color_dialog.show()
    result = color_dialog.exec_()

    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(context.variable("layer_id"))

    if result == 1:
        color = color_dialog.color().name()
        feature["comment"] = color
        layer.updateFeature(feature)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved with an Action in the attribute table.

###### Add a new action

Select the Actions tab in the layer properties:

[image]

- Add a new action with the [image] button.
- Make sure the *Show in Attribute Table* option is checked

###### Configure the Action

Be sure to change the *Type* to *Python*.

[image]

###### The code for the action

In this example it will update the field called `colour`.

```
from qgis.utils import iface

layer = iface.activeLayer()

color_dialog = QgsColorDialog()
color_dialog.show()

result = color_dialog.exec_()

if result == 1:
    color = color_dialog.color().name()
    feature = layer.getFeature([%$id%])
    
    if not layer.isEditable():
        layer.startEditing()
    feature["colour"] = color
    layer.updateFeature(feature)
    layer.commitChanges()
```

###### Visualisation

To demonstrate the action working, I made a rule-based symbology with two simple rules. Whether there is a value in the `colour` field, or not.

[image]

For the symbology of the `colour is not null` rule, use an expression to change the fill to the colour that is inserted by the action.

[image]

###### Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I got an error : `NameError: name 'iface' is not defined` at line 1 when running the action.

Comment: Solved by replacing first line with : `layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Great that you solved it :) I also added the import to the code in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I have since discovered this can be done much more simply using a Color Widget for the field. No Python required.

Create a new `Text` field (mine is named `colour`)

In the Attribute Form:

1. Choose *Drag and Drop Designer* from the uppermost dropdown.
2. Select the `colour` field in the *Form Layout* pane
3. Choose *Color* as the widget type for the field

[image]

In the layer symbology, either:

- set a rule as in my other answer

or, even more simply:

- use the data-defined override for the symbol fill:

[image]

With the `colour` field name as the expression.

[image: Use field]

Make sure the layer is in edit mode and you can colour features using the widget.

[image]